# What does 13A on my computer monitor power plug means?

Tags: electrical, socket, cord-and-plug

I have a BENQ GW2470HL computer monitor.

The monitor power plug says 13A. What does that mean exactly?

[image]

The [monitor specs](https://www.benq.com/en-ap/monitor/stylish/gw2470hl/specifications.html) say it needs 30W. In my country(India), the voltage is 230 V.

If I divide 30w/230V I get 0.130 ampere/s. Can I plug this into a 5 amp socket? From where does 13A comes from?

Comment: the 13 A would come from a short circuit ... possibly from an accidental cutting of the power cord

Answer (score 6):

That's the maximum rating for the plug. It doesn't change anything about the current in your attached device. If you exceed that current for some reason, the plug will open the circuit for protection.

Answer (score 2):

The red part is a fuse holder with a window to allow you to see the rating (13 Amperes) of the fuse mounted inside. The small gaps at either end of the red part let you pry it out to replace the fuse.

Note that that is the rating of the plug/cord assembly. The monitor, per its specifications, will only draw 30W or about 1/8A as you have correctly calculated.